# Javascript function is not defined error on existing function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function that is to be called on form submission to send out an ajax request. The problem is, when I try and submit the form, I get the following error: "checkCustomerExists is not defined" What is additionally strange is that I have a staging and production site, and they are currently identical, and the staging site works no problem, but the production site is the one having the issues. Here is what I have so far on both sites:

```
 <script>

        function checkCustomerExists(){
            var phone = $('input[name=phone]').val();
            var email = $('input[name=email]').val();
            loadingModal();
            if (phone !== '' && email !== '' && !checkedIfAccount){
                var data = {
                    email,
                    phone
                };
                checkedIfAccount = true;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ shop.metafields.API.doesCustExist }}",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    method: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(json){
                        if (json.exists){
                            if(!json.active){
                                var contactName;
                                var contactType;
                                if (json.email){
                                    contactName = json.email;
                                    contactType = 'email';
                                } else if(json.phone) {
                                    contactName = json.phone;
                                    contactType = 'phone number';
                                }
                                $('#error-message').html('Your account with the '+contactType+' <span>'+contactName+'</span> has not yet been activated. An email has been sent to you with an activation link to finish creating your account.');
                                $('#account-exists-modal').modal('show');

                            }
                            else if (json.email){
                                $('#error-message').html('There is an existing account with the registered email <span style="color: red">'+json.email+'</span>. Please Log In with the provided form.');
                                $('#account-exists-modal').modal('show');
                            } else if (json.phone){
                                $('#error-message').html('There is an existing account with the phone number <span style="color: red">'+json.phone.replace(/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?(\s)?[-.●]?([0-9]{3})(\s)?[-.●]?([0-9]{4})$/, '($1) $3-$5')+'</span>. Please Log In with the provided form.');
                                $('#account-exists-modal').modal('show');
                            }
                            doesAcctExist = true;
                    } else {
                        addCustomeToPro();

                    }
                });
                checkedIfAccount = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
<script>
    var checkedIfAccount = false;
    var doesAcctExist = false;

    $('#add_prof').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var professions = [];
            $('.prof_check:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                professions.push('Profession:' + $(this).val());
            });

            if (!validateForm(professions)) {
                unloadButton();
                return false;
            }
        checkCustomerExists();

    });
</script>
```

I can't figure out why one works and the other doesn't. They are both on Shopify stores as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you want us to compare the code line by line? Can you just tell us where the difference is?

Comment: Can you combine the two scripts?

Comment: There is no difference, that's the problem. They are exactly the same, but one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: @ic3b3rg The two scripts have to be separate for modular purposes.The top script is used on other pages while the botton one is only used on one page.

Comment: So then please just remove the second code block, and just write that your code runs fine in one environment and not the other. Please include *any* difference of where those scripts are positioned in the HTML document. If the order is different, then no need to look further: that is the cause.

Comment: ok, can you combine them to test and see if it fixes the problem?

Comment: There are no other problems reported by the console upon loading your application?

Comment: @Icepickle There are a couple other minor issues, but they are from Shopify Apps and they also exist on staging.

Comment: Are you sure that the final code loaded into users browser is actually identical ?Issues like this are common when 1 environment has cached code from previous version(which is missing required update) and the other env has updated its cache. Also, production environments usually have additional javascript/css pre-processing/packaging steps which may alter the final output in a bad way if not configured properly. Compare the actual code loaded by your browser.